# Extracting string between : and next whitespace

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to extract the parameter variables :country and :age from this statement and store them in a string[] or List or something like that. But what is the easiest way to do that? Regex? String-Methods?

```
string sql = "select firstname, age, country from Table where country = :country and age > :age order by age";
```

My approach so far :

```
string[] sub = sql.Split(' ');
        List<string> parameter = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < sub.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sub[i].StartsWith(':'))
            {
                parameter.Add(sub[i]);
            }
        }    //
```

Comment: Could your queries have line breaks? Whitespace other than spaces (ie: a tab immediately preceding the `:` parameter indicator)? Could you have the parameter indicator in string literals (ie  `select title, description from books where title like '%:%';`)?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I am reading sql statements from a File and store them in a string, I need to know the names of the parameters. Line breaks are possible everywhere.

Comment: So it's even worse: you could have all of that, and comments that might include text mimicking the parameter format. Unfortunately, you may have fallen into the case where what at first seems like a simple extraction actually requires as much work as writing a functional and complete lexer/parser covering the entire language.

Comment: Nah, comments are not a problem, these statements are small, but a lot of them.

Comment: I am afraid that for an absolute correct solution (e.g. avoiding match on string constant contents, etc.) you should use an SQL parser. Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx

Comment: I edited the question with my approach, but I think its not the best and efficient way to do that.

Comment: In addition to all the comments above, if you simply don't care about any advanced cases, you can use a regular expression: `new Regex(@":[a-z0-9_]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: @Nathan You're right, and for instance, if the where clause would be `... OR (age is null or age > :age)`, you wouldn't find a space immediately after the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [Regular Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0)?

```
public static void FindMatches()
{
    string text = "select firstname, age, country from Table where country = :country and age > :age order by age";
    Regex regex = new Regex(@":\w+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
:country
:age
```

`:` will match the [colon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)) character 
`\w` will match word boundary (alphanumeric and underscore)
`+` match 1 or more the preceding token

Comment: this solution seems to be the best way. thank you